# update fork to upstream regularry

Tags: git, git-fork

I have the fork of some very huge and actively developed project. Usually I update to upstream every 2 month, but this process very painful - it takes a week, work stops, and after merge many bugs appear.
At fist I tried just `git rebase` but there ware a lot of conflicts on every commit, so I decided squash all my changes to 1 commit and rebase it on upstream, but I loose my commit history.
Are there any approach to make this process less painful?

Comment: Make smaller changes? Split the work?

Comment: @Jeroen3 Can you explain you in more details? Maybe you can do it in the answer instead of comment.

Comment: Use [git rerere](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) when rebasing

Comment: If you see any unexpected conflicts, which you think would not have happened if you did it without git, you might ask specifically about them. Otherwise there is really no royal path.

Comment: I don't think in this case `git rerere` would help because conflicts are different each time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know but:

> Usually I update to upstream every **2 month**, but this process very painful - it takes a week, work stops, and **after merge many bugs appear**.

I think, that if you are 2 months behind on an actively developed master you are begging for trouble.

1. I suggest you make smaller features. Perform smaller merges more often. But this might not be feasible if you can't split your features.
2. Or, merge master into your feature branch to **test it**, then update upstream.
   You have to test it anyway. That way the bugs appear with you, and not with the maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to maintain own patches over fast changing project there is no magic button. `git rebase` is a right tool for this because does good job of bookkeeping but it cannot resolve conflicts by itself. There are some things which may help you. They are mostly irrelevant to technology you use.

- (as suggested by other answer) try to update more often, and add unit tests
- make your changes smaller, do not try to fix upstream coding style etc. Disable in your IDE automatic reformatting. Sometimes it makes sense to violate the style regarding for example indentation.
- structure carefully your changes. Divide it into commits like:

  - non-functional refactoring of the upstream code, which is going to prepare project for your features inclusion. They will conflict almost always but you can redo them relatively easily from scratch if you have high-level description around (like "extract X functionality into function with Y name")
  - pieces of logic which is exclusive to you features implemented in new files added by you. Then they would never conflict.
  - inclusion of your features into the project by adding or changing couple of lines here and there. They would sometimes conflict but should be easy to redo.
- contribute your changes upstream, fully or partly